# Filter list based on previous calendar month

Tags: 2013, list-view, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem

We have a list and need to create a view based on previous calendar month.

I have created two new calculated Date and Tine columns:

- `_StartPreviousMonth = DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created)-1,1)`
- `_EndPrevioousMonth = DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created),1)-1`

These are working as expected.

An item created in November shows start of 11/01/2023 and end of 11/30/2023. We are now in December 2023, and I need the view to show only items in November. The view filters are `_StartPreviousMonth is less than or equal to [TODAY]` and `_EndPrevioousMonth is greater than or equal to [TODAY]`. This returns all items from December 2023. I need to be able to pull November’s items. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why `_EndPrevioousMonth` and not `_EndPreviousMonth`? 

Answer (score 0):

> An item created in November shows start of 11/01/2023 and end of
> 11/30/2023

No, with the formula you used, an item created in November will have 10/01/2023 and 10/31/2023. And this is correct regarding the name of the column (previous month, not current month!) and the formula (MONTH - 1).

**My suggestion: create calculated columns with current month**

```
_StartCurrentMonth = DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created),1)
_EndCurrentMonth = DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created)+1,1)-1
```

And then for the view, use a filter with `[TODAY]-30` but in some case, it will not work (for example: in February/March).

[image: filter today - 30]